# Redirecting www to non-www, http to https and domain.com to domain.com/index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Am trying to use .htaccess to redirect:

1) all www to non-www e.g. www.example.com/page.php to example.com/page.php

2) all http to https e.g. http://example.com/page.php to https://example.com/page.php

3) the domain (and subfolders) to their index.php page e.g. https://example.com to https://example.com/index.php and https://example.com/en-gb/ to https://example.com/en-gb/index.php

I can get 1) and 2) working correctly with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But I am struggling with including 3) as well. I have tried this but no luck:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

**Update - tried this but no luck**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI}

Redirect / https://example.com/index.php
```

**Second update - tried this but same as before I get index.php added recursively to the URL:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/index.php$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your browser cache and put the following code at your main directory `.htaccess` file , no need to go every folder and put code there :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
# the two lines above will catch both http://www & http:// and force https:// 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
# the three lines above will catch only https://www and redirect it to none wwww 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule  ^    /index.php [R=302,L,NE]
# the two lines above will force index.php to domain when request to index.php comes without it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/$    /$1/index.php [R=302,L,NE]
# the two lines above will force index.php to any directory when request to index.php comes without it
```

Test it , if it's oK , change every `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection

Comment: Better than my own answer as all gets done in one .htaccess file - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well - thanks for your help everyone :)

I eventually got there. In case this helps anyone else with the same problem... this went in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/index.php
```

And this in each folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUESTFILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/en-gb/index.php
```